# Properties of $\inf_{m \geq n}f_m$ and $\sup_{m \geq n}f_m$ for a convergent sequence $f_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, reference-request

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of real-valued functions converging to $f$. Define
$g_n = \inf_{m \geq n} f_m$ and $h_n = \sup_{m \geq n} f_m$.

Where can I find properties of $g_n$ and $h_n$ (such as convergence results in function spaces and increasing/decreasing properties)? looking for a reference.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $f$?

Comment: Let's say in $L^\infty$ on some domain. Or anything appropriate, I want to understand these types of modified sequences.

Comment: Notice that $g_n$ is decreasing and $h_n$ is increasing. Therefore either they diverges to $\infty $ or, if they are bounded, they converges.

Comment: @joshua I think you mean $g_n$ is increasing